Changing Gemini Browser Interface so Return doesn't Post the Question
When using (Google) Gemini in the Chrome browser (or Edge), it's normal to want to do multiline inputs.  This can be done with shift-return (or equivalently shift-enter).
But the tendency is so accidently hit the unshifted version which uploads a half formed question.
Is there any way to suppress the posting of a question when hitting return (i.e., enter), i.e., to make a return just a return.
